# How to think algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm studying Algebra and came across an article by Dr. Keith Devlin [1] where he states that Algebra is not about doing arithmetic rather analytic, qualitative reasoning about numbers.

I can't find much info on this topic most importantly about qualitative reasoning. I'm really good at analytic reasoning but in most cases I didn't found such a problem in Khan Academy to solve. It looks like that I'm doing arithmetic by finding what's X and simplifying it further.

[1] http://profkeithdevlin.org/2011/11/20/what-is-algebra/

Comment: I assume you are referring to middle-school algebra rather than abstract algebra.  I would say that while learning how to manipulate equations is all well and good (*and builds upon what you should already know about arithmetic*) the other important aspect you should familiarize yourself with is learning how to take real world problems you want to solve and figure out how to translate them into maths.  That's to say, rather than solely focusing on how to manipulate an equation once you have it, you should learn how to arrive at said equations in the first place.  He may be talking about this.

Comment: For instance, those sort of questions like "*When I was $6$ years old on new years eve, my sister was $3$.  This coming new years eve I will be $40$ years old.  How old will my sister be?*"  Learning how to express this mathematically is the first and arguably most important step to solving it, more so than the manipulation of the numbers and variables that occur after.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'd argue that thinking and expressing are two differ things. I can express a problem mathematically but I feel like a robot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A an example from my personal history.

In school, I was given polynomials to factor.  e.g. $x^2 + 3x + 2 = (x+1)(x+2)$ then was told that $(x+1)(x+2) = 0$ implies that $x+1 = 0$ or $x+ 2 = 0.$  But, it was never explained why that would be, or I wasn't paying attention, or I didn't care at the time.  I could do the steps, get the answer, but didn't really know why.

One day it struck me....  $(x+1)(x+2)$ is two things multiplied together.  A zero thing multiplied by anything makes zero, and two non-zero things multiplied together makes a non-zero thing.  This was a shift in thinking for me.  Integers have factors, polynomials have factors, polynomials are not integers, but they have similar characteristics.

This lead thinking beyond x as a stand-in for a real number, and thinking about the polynomial as an object in itself.  Math became less of an exercise in getting the right answers and more about seeing the patterns and the structures.